# Chrome Extension Chaing Content From the Javascript

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So, I am trying to do a basic Google Chrome Hello World kind of extension. Can someone explain me why the below code doesn't work? Thanks.

popup.js:

```
document.getElementById("foobar").innerHTML = "Hello Chrome Extensions";
```

popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello Chrome</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <div id="foobar"></div>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am following the "framework" of http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html.

Comment: Swap the order of the lines `<script .. >` and `<div ..>` OR wrap the code in `popup.js` in `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { ...code here... });`.

Comment: Thanks! What a silly mistake. Consider adding it as an answer so that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved in two ways:

1. Swap the order of `<script .. >` and `<div ..>`.
2. Wrap the code in `popup.js` in a domready event:

   ```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
       // Code here...
   });
   ```

Your code failed because the `<div>` was unknown at the time of executing the script.