# how to interact between google-chrome extension files

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How can i call function from `backgroundPage.js` into action page `popupPage.js`
**This is my code**

**popupPage.js**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../background.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="bu_1">clickMe</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**And backgroundPage.js**

```
var button = document.getElementById("bu_1");
button.addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log("bu_1 clicked !");
},false);
```

The console show error message says

> "Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null"

Any help !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension Chaing Content From the Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325447/chrome-extension-chaing-content-from-the-javascript)

Comment: Isn't the id of the button `bu_1` not `highAss`?

Comment: Adding to what @BeardFist said, you shouldn't load the js file for your background like that. Maybe a `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` is desirable. So try warping the entire code into a function block.